# jQuery - Extract just text from complex html page

Tags: jquery, text

My jQuery AJAX client is interfacing with an API which usually returns JSON but, in some situations, returns a complex, pretty, human-readable web page.

For debugging purposes, I'd like to log these cases, saving just the text from the page.  I thought this would be a trivial `$(result).text()`, but that seems to retain a lot of the non-text components too, particularly the contents of stylesheet refs.

For example:

`$('<html>Some text<style>body { height: 100%;}</style><script type="text/javascript">function f() { return 42;}</script>some more text</body></html>').text();`

gives

`"Some textbody { height: 100%;}function f() { return 42;}some more text"`

where I'd like to see

`"Some textsomemore text"`

Second example (edited in later), because this needs to search recursively:

`<html>abc<script>f=3;</script><div>def<script>g=7</script>ghi</div></html>`

Should return:

`"abcdefghi"`

without either `f=3` or `g=7`.

What's the easiest way to get just the text?  I don't need this to be perfect, nor to handle hairy edge cases; just not to flood my log with hundreds of lines of JavaScript and CSS.

=-=-=-=

Note: the accepted answer works in many contexts, but not all; see my comments to it. It's not clear if the problem has to do with jQuery version, something weird in Chrome extensions or, most likely, something messed up in my environment. The symptom of the failing context is that filter does not remove matching elements if they are nested inside other elements.

Comment: `$(result).text()` should do the trick but if this is still returning HTML contents, then there is a possibility that HTML encoded texts are coming. try `$($(result)).text()`

Comment: Nope, thanks. That did not help.
I'll edit my question to give an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the elements what you don't want to be participated in text extraction like "Script, Style" etc.

Try this:

```
var str1 = '<html>Some text<style>body { height: 100%;}</style><script type="text/javascript">function f() { return 42;}</script>some more text</body></html>';
var str2 = '<html>abc<script>f=3;</script><div>def<script>g=7</script>ghi</div></html>';

function extractText(htmlString){
    return $(htmlString).filter(function(i, elm){ 
        return !$(elm).is("script, style");
    }).text();
}

console.log(extractText(str1)); // "Some textsome more text"
console.log(extractText(str2)); // "abcdefghi"
```

Comment: That's close, but doesn't catch everything, because filter does not search recursively.

For example:
$("<html>abc<script>f=3;</script><div>def<script>g=7</script>ghi</div></html>").filter(function(i,e){return !$(e).is('script');}).text()

"abcdefg=7ghi"

I'll edit this into my question, so it's more readable than here.

Comment: that works in both the conditions. Could you pease test again

Comment: though  I have edited the code to enclose that in a function... but that anyway does exactly what you are looking for. :)

Comment: My mistake; not sure what faked me out, sorry.
Your code does work for the two cases I gave, but not for the real case from which I simplified. I'm trying to build a proper small failing case now.

Comment: Now I'm really puzzled!!

Your code works 100% fine in a regular Chrome console, on both str2 and on my long original example.

But, when I test in the Console window of a Chrome extension, then I get abcdefg=7ghi for str2.

Comment: I wonder if this depends on jQuery version??
In the working chrome console (of this stackoverflow page), jQuery 1.7.1 is running, and I get:

> $.filter
(a,b,c){c&&(a=":not("+a+")");return b.length===1?f.find.matchesSelector(b[0],a)?[b[0]]:[]:f.find.matches(a,b)}

but, in the Chrome extension, I'm running jQuery 2.1.4, and see:

> $.filter
(a,b,c){var d=b[0];return c&&(a=":not("+a+")"),1===b.length&&1===d.nodeType?n.find.matchesSelector(d,a)?[d]:[]:n.find.matches(a,n.grep(b,function(a){return 1===a.nodeType}))}

Comment: I tried what I could have done. Best of luck for your integration part... :)

Comment: Yup, thanks.  I will accept your answer, for the sake of the next searcher, but add an edit clarifying my question.